# Curvature of hyperbolic surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, curvature, noneuclidean-geometry

So from what I understand the curvature of a surface by calculated by inversing the radius of the osculating circle.  But if a hyperbolic surface have a negative curvature, wouldn't that imply the radius of the osculating circle be negative?  How exactly can the radius of a circle be negative?  Many Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing curvature of planar curves and curvature of surfaces.

Comment: In particular, the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) of a surface is *not* the inverse of the radius of some osculating circle.

Comment: a surface has TWO osculating circles if they are on opposite sides of the surface then the Gaussian curvature is negative, if the gaussian curvature is negative and constant then you have an surface for hyperbolic geometry. (ps not to be confused with at least two other definitions of what an hyperbolic plane is)